# Saving images from WebView(Windows Phone WinAPI)

Tags: windows, webview, browser, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently creating a Windows Phone Web Browser and plan on making it universal so I decided to target Windows RT.

After a while I encountered an issue and I don't even know how to start. I was wondering how I can get a context menu to display when I hold down an image in WebView and save it to storage. Any help guys?